# Can mercurial pull changes from forked repo into a new branch?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch, branching-and-merging

I have a project, biocommons/hgvs. A contributor forked the project, made some changes, and submitted a pull request. I'd like to make some minor changes to those commits, and I'd prefer to do so in a feature branch.

Is there a way to pull the PR commits into a new branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pull them in another branch in a sense how mercurial uses branch (as in named branch created by `hg branch`).

However, you simply can continue to work on top of your latest commit and later merge your head and the head created by the pull request, thus both, yours and their head being anonymous branches. (IMHO this is the beauty - every head can work on its own, no need to expressly branch or name things)
If you still want a name, you can stick a bookmarks onto the head of the pulled changes; they work very similar to 'full' branches except that they can be changed and moved.

If you really need and want the changesets to be in a named branch, then pull from the forked repository, create the named feature branch manually and use rebase or histedit to move the commits to the just created feature branch.

Comment: I did end up creating a named branch and rebasing as described. For anyone who comes this way again, there was one additional key: the pulled commits were "public" in the forked repo, and I had to revert them to drafts in the main repo with `hg phase -f -d REV` (where REV is the ancestor of a series of pulled changes).